# is it possible to have multiple forms in the same html document?

Tags: html, forms

is it possible to use multiple form in the same html document with different method(without getting any problem),
for example the document is devided into 3 parts
with a form for every single part ?

```
<form id="form1" method="POST">..other elements goes here..</form>
<form id="form2" method="GET">..other elements goes here..</form>
<form id="form3" method="POST">..other elements goes here..</form>
```

Comment: absolutely! you can have

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Is there a particular reason you would think otherwise?  Did you *try*?

Answer (score 0):

A page can contain an infinity of forms. For that case, I see two main solutions.

**1. Using different action addresses**
Indicate the *action* attribute in the *form* tag with different url.

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="/login">..other elements goes here..</form>
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="/signup">..other elements goes here..</form>
```

**2. Using a hidden field as flag**
Add an extra hidden value that your action can check to branch your program flow.

```
<form id="form1" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="service" value="login" />
   ..other elements goes here..
</form>
<form id="form1" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="service" value="signup" />
   ..other elements goes here..
</form>
```